# Регулярное выражение js/jQuery для поиска адреса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите пожалуйста составить регулярное выражение на js или jQuery,
для поддержания старого кода (общее количество страниц +500, в ручную править не вариант). На странице есть 1 ссылка вида *example.com/article/123* 1-3 цифры. Эти цифры и надо получить и передать дальше в обработчик. Классы ссылки могут меняться, по этому кроме как искать в DOM других вариантов не придумал. C регулярными выражениями что на php что на js всегда беда.

Answer (score 0):

```
 /example\.com\/article\/(\d{1-3})/g
```

`\.` экранированный символ `.`
`\/` экранированный символ `/`
 
`\d` любая цифра (equal to [0-9])
`{1-3}` количество вхождений от 1 до 3 
`g` все совпадения

Тест онлайн: https://regex101.com/r/LB9mLt/2